# How to determine on one sample or two sample test, Z or t test

Tags: statistics, static-analysis

If you would like to know if there is significant difference on an attitude between two diverse groups (Let's say A and B). I drew a sample of 31 from  A and a sample of 33 B. Two sample are independent from each other, given the facts:

1) Do I need to run one sample or two sample test, and why?
2-)Considering sample sizes, should i run a T test or Z, and why?
3) Is it a one tailed or two tailed test, and why?

Answer (score 0):

this [link](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/basic-statistics-and-graphs/hypothesis-tests/tests-of-means/types-of-t-tests/) will explain to you when to use one or two sample test. Since you are comparing the responses from two groups (A and B), two sample test is more appropriate.  2) Run a T-test if population standard deviation is unknown or if known, sample observation is less than 30. Use z-test if population standard deviation is known and sample size is equal or greater than 30 ([link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/z-test-vs-t-test-arunmozhi-ilango)). 3) When you have a null hypothesis that group A is not equal to group B, then use two tailed test, if your null hypothesis is one sided (mean of group A > mean of group B or vice-versa) then it is a one-tailed test.  Also, you did not mention that your observation is numerical or categorical.  If categorical, you use [chi-square][3] test rather than t-test.  Hope this helps.